# How can I get only 9:44 AM only from the below XML using Xpath Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver

I would like to take only `9:44 AM` from the below HTML DOM:

```
<td style="width:8%;">
10/12
<div class="clear"></div>
9:44 AM
</td>
```

If I am using xpath- `(//td[@style='width:8%;'])[1]`- will give me an output of

```
10/12
9:44 AM
```

I dont even want to split after taking the whole value. I just need `9:44 AM`.

One more thing, `9:44 AM` is the time which is dynamic.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This XPath,

```
//td[@style='width:8%;']/div[@class="clear"]/following-sibling::text()
```

will select

```
9:44 AM
```

for the input XML as requested.

You can wrap the above XPath in `normalize-space()` to remove any unwanted leading and trailing whitespace.

> One more thing, 9:44 AM is the time which is dynamic.

It will select a snapshot of the text as of the time the XPath is applied.

---

**Update**: Without `text()`...

Saurabh Gaur helpfully pointed out that Selenium does not support XPath `text()` node selection.   Ugh.

Here's one way to work around that limitation:

```
substring-after(normalize-space(//td[@style='width:8%;']), ' ')
```

This takes the string value of the targeted `td`, normalizes spaces, and the takes the substring after the first space to skip the date and yield the time alone.

Comment: FYI `text()` node of the xpath doesn't supported by selenium webdriver, this xpath is absolutely correct but wouldn't work with selenium to fetching the desired text. Thanks..

Comment: @SaurabhGaur: Ugh, but thanks for mentioning.  I've updated the answer.